# Serilog's sublogger filters do not work properly

Tags: c#, logging, serilog

Here is my simple config:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.Level < LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning))
        .WriteTo.File(
            Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logs/warnings"), "log.txt"),
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .WriteTo.Logger(l => l
        .Filter.ByExcluding(e => e.Level < LogEventLevel.Error)
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error))
        .WriteTo.File(
            Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/logs/errors"), "log.txt"),
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
            flushToDiskInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    .CreateLogger();
```

What I want, is to separate **Error** and **Warning** log event levels. However, all my **Error** logs are still written to *~/logs/warnings* folder.

[Same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49795291/serilog-sublogger-include-and-exclude-filters-does-not-work) has no answers at all.

How can I separate those logs properly, what's wrong with config?

Comment: Answer given off-site here: https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/583

Comment: @BenVoigt I've checked this answer multiple times, I have absolutely the same config, where is the key difference? Why **Error** passes to **Warning** logger despite of the `IncludingOnly` filter?

Comment: In my link, it appears that the thing that changed between the problem and solution was adding a call to `MinimumLevel()` on the `LoggerConfiguration` object, and again on the sublogger.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code, it's separating error and warning log event

```
Log.Logger = 
    new LoggerConfiguration()                 
        .MinimumLevel.Debug()                 
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)                 
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()                 
        .WriteTo.Console()                 
        .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Error)                     
        .WriteTo.File(@"Log\LogError.txt"))                 
        .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc                     
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e => e.Level == LogEventLevel.Warning)                     
        .WriteTo.File(@"Log\LogWarning.txt"))                 
        .WriteTo.File(@"Log\log.txt")                 
        .CreateLogger();
```